# calculate cells in range if user changes any value of the cell in range

Tags: excel, vba, calculated-field

i have this code that works and calculates A1 based on what's in A2:A5. if i have "1" in A2:A5 then A1 is 4. now i change A1 to "3" and want to see what A2:A5 will be, but it bounces back to "4". how do i modify this macro to make this happen? i need this to work for any cell in A1:A5 range.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)'

Dim A(1 To 5) As Range

Set A(1) = Range("A1")
Set A(2) = Range("A2")
Set A(3) = Range("A3")
Set A(4) = Range("A4")
Set A(5) = Range("A5")

If Intersect(Range("A1:A5"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False
    A(1) = A(2) + A(3) + A(4) + A(5)
    A(2) = A(1) - A(3) - A(4) - A(5)
    A(3) = A(1) - A(2) - A(4) - A(5)
    A(4) = A(1) - A(2) - A(3) - A(5)
    A(5) = A(1) - A(2) - A(3) - A(4)
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: you are changing all 5 each time.  I think  you need to do 5 different IF to exclude changing the one that was changed manually.

Comment: thanks Scott, i figured i'd need " ifs" and i tried different loops before and nothing worked. im quite new to VBA . can you help me with "IF" code for this macro?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) '

    Dim A(1 To 5) As Range

    Set A(1) = Range("A1")
    Set A(2) = Range("A2")
    Set A(3) = Range("A3")
    Set A(4) = Range("A4")
    Set A(5) = Range("A5")

    If Intersect(Range("A1:A5"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Intersect(A(1), Target) Is Nothing Then A(1) = A(2) + A(3) + A(4) + A(5)
        If Intersect(A(2), Target) Is Nothing Then A(2) = A(1) - A(3) - A(4) - A(5)
        If Intersect(A(3), Target) Is Nothing Then A(3) = A(1) - A(2) - A(4) - A(5)
        If Intersect(A(4), Target) Is Nothing Then A(4) = A(1) - A(2) - A(3) - A(5)
        If Intersect(A(5), Target) Is Nothing Then A(5) = A(1) - A(2) - A(3) - A(4)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: this code changes only A2 and no other cell in range when i change A1 to a new value. when i move on to change A3 then only A1 changes. what would be the code that recalculate all other cells if one cell changes?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do.  This is the logic you provided, not mine.  How would you "spread" out the changes, or in other works, if all had `1` and you changed A1 to 10, what would you expect.  The logic you provided will  only change A2 to 7 and the others would stay the same.  You have to decide the rules, Excel no us can read your mind.

Comment: Apologies for being not clear! what i am trying to achieve is that if user changes any one of the cells in range, the remaining cells will recalculate automatically based on that change.  do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It does recalculate, but it makes all the changes in one cell.  The calcs are all valid.  so the question is what would you expect to see if A1 was changed to `10` when all the others start at `1`?

Comment: you made me realize i have a different problem at hand.thank you!!!  i wasn't seeing the obvious! i need to use Solver for A1 and optimize A2:A5.